# Nook Simple Touch: erratic or unresponsive touch-screen

Tags: nook, nook-simple-touch, touchscreen

I have had a rooted (with NookManager) Nook Simple Touch that worked perfectly until I went travelling across tropical countries. Since then, I have seen a progressive degradation of the touchscreen, specifically I noted the following:

- Buttons/icons in the lower half of the screen, when tapped, do no respond. Instead, buttons/icons directly above them (on the upper part of the screen) do respond to the action.
- When the keyboard is active and letters are tapped, you get one of these random behaviours:

  1. the letter appears on the screen, but 2 or 3 of them, even if the letter is tapped once.
  2. the letter above the one tapped, appears on screen: e.g. I press "q" and "a" appears on screen; I press "backspace" and the letter "p" appears on screen.

Following the recommendations of many forums, I cleaned thoroughly my screen, however this does not seem to resolve the problem. I also performed a factory reset and re-root, still the problem persists (though, after a new factory reset, the erratic behaviour is less frequent).

The only thing that changed is the fact that I am now travelling in hotter countries and maybe the Nook is sensitive to temperatures constantly above 30C.

Has anyone experienced similar problems?

Thanks

Marco

---

Comment: I have a similar, although not identical, problem. My rooted nook simple touch was working perfectly, then just recently had become extremely unresponsive during reading. It still responds normally during other use, but actually reading is incredibly difficult and sometimes when trying to turn a page or something, it will display the error message about the Reader app taking too long to respond. Unlike yourself, there has been no particular change in climate for my nst. I too have tried cleaning the screen, but unsurprisingly as only the Reader app appears to be crashing, this didn't change an

Answer (score 1):

I found that the elastic straps of the cover I was using (one at each corner) had permanently deformed the nook st sufficiently to unalign the IR light grid over the screen. I'm now getting the nook to respond by bending the top front corners forward to realign the ir grid.(by placing my thumb at top front centre and my index and little fingers on the back of the two upper corners)
Awkward, but it works until I can get another Nook st.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same problem for years. Until I found a solution when I realized that it looked like the Nook required re-calibration. You know like letting it know where the bottom corners are and so on. I tried the following trick and it worked and have been working 100% ever since.

When this bug happens all I have to do is to swipe my finger around the screen perimeter.Something like first putting my finger to the top right corner, then move it to the bottom right corner while touching the screen, then to the bottom left corner and so on until getting back to the corner where I started from.

I guess the complete loop is not necessary really, it worked fine when I stopped in the top right corner too. And most likely it can be done by moving to the opposite direction or starting from a different corner. I just was too lazy to experiment once the problem was solved )

I hope it helps someone and will work not only for me.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer here
https://tomelliott.com/devices/fixing-unresponsive-nook-touch-screen

worked for me!

From the link:

1. Make sure your Nook is fully charged. Mine was probably below 10% charge when the screen stopped responding.
2. Dust the screen and make sure there are no hairs, grains of sand or anything else that could potentially cause interference.
3. Carefully slide a piece of paper against the screen and where it meets the side of the Nook and also try blowing these edges to get rid of any other dirt around the sides of the screen.